# What is Tinkledeath made out of?

Tags: inheritance-cycle

In *The Inheritance Cycle*, what is Tinkledeath, Angela's sword, made out of?
Eragon says it may be diamond, but it never actually says what it is.

Comment: "*Not much is known about Tinkledeath's history, much like Angela the Herbalist, but it appeared that she was very comfortable with it and may have had it for a long time. **It may be made from dragon egg shell, due to its strength and the noise it makes when struck.** -"*  https://inheritance.fandom.com/wiki/Tinkledeath

Comment: " It was a sword made out of 'neither metal nor stone'". Diamond is stone, right? So not that.

Comment: If it is dragon shell, it would have to be made with magic, but ti very well could be.

Comment: It is enchanted diamond. christopher paolini said so himself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It is made out of solid diamond.

Quoting from Christopher Paolini on his website about a Make-a-wish he participated in:

> The young man, Brenden, wanted a replica of Angela’s sword, Albitr (aka Tinkledeath), from the Inheritance Cycle. This posed certain problems above-and-beyond the normal difficulties of crafting a sword, because—as you may remember—**Tinkledeath is made out of solid diamond.** Yikes!
> <sub>[Tinkledeath: A Make-A-Wish Story](https://www.paolini.net/2016/06/22/tinkledeath-make-wish-story/)</sub>

And from the video of him speaking about this:

> He wanted a replica of Angela's sword, Tinkledeath, also known as Albitr. And if you've read the Inheritance Cycle you may remember that **Albitr/Tinkledeath is made completely from diamond—tip to pommel.**
> <sub>[Christopher Paolini Showcases a Replica of Tinkledeat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eO5xT-HoUWg)</sub>